# How to list all files on all hard drives with output in MS-DOS batch?

Tags: batch, ms-dos

How can I list all files (including system and hidden) on all hard drives (not removable drives)?

I think in something like a:

```
dir -a -h *.* /s > file.txt
```

but this is for the specific drive where I'm.

How can I do something like that but with C:, D:, etc, 
but I don't know the DOS's name of the drivers, and i need a .bat to do this (an automatic listing). Implementer can't also know the names of drivers.

Comment: Please if you vote down, comment the reasons to know how to improve my question. Thanks.

Comment: My guess would be that someone downvoted because for me at least the very first item in a google search was essentially the answer. Hence "does not show any research effort"

Comment: I really did not found anything useful :(

Comment: Are you restricted to MS-DOS or can you use any version (FreeDOS, 4DOS etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can do the trick to check removable drivers without medias!
http://www.ericphelps.com/batch/samples/adrive.bat.txt.
It's a not documented function!

Answer (score 3):

There is a program that can detect CD drives ([`FINDCD.EXE`](http://www.google.com/search?q=findcd.exe)) that comes on some boot disks (including the Windows 98 Emergency Boot Disk) which you can use in a batch file to skip them:

```
@echo off
findcd.exe
if (%1)==() goto start

:dirit
if not exist %1:\*.* goto done
if (%1)==(%CDROM%) goto done
dir /a/s/o %1:\*.* >> c:\Files.txt
goto done

:start
for %i in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do call %0 %i
goto done

:done
```

I just threw this together off the top of my head (with no testing since I am currently in Windows), but it should do the trick for the most part. Note that floppy drives are *always* assigned a drive letter starting with A while hard-drives *always* start at C, so this skips A and B.

There is also a program that can detect RAM drives ([`FINDRAMD.EXE`](http://www.google.com/search?q=findramd.exe)) which you can use to detect and skip RAM drives if you have those, but that requires more work (and a separate batch file). Look at `SETRAMD.BAT` which is usually included for an example.

Comment: @user3186092: the question is tagged as `MS-DOS` and the syntax is different from the windows scripts.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only using DOS then here is a way to detect the type of drives attached:

http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeSnippets.php#Snippets.DrivesAndTypes

This doesn't work from Windows 7 Command Prompt so I have been unable to expand it further but it shouldn't be too difficult to add a loop to test for fixed disks and perform the dir.

Answer (score 1):

You're *very* lucky.  I still had my old `DS.BTM` script (a cut down and modernized version of a `SYSINF.BAT` that I picked up many years ago) on one machine, from which this is an excerpt.  This requires JP Software's 4DOS, which is now freeware.  As you can see, it picks up the `LASTDISK` value from DOS, and explicitly avoids removable and network drives.

```
@echo off
loadbtm on
do d = %@ascii[A] to %@ascii[%_lastdisk]

   iff %@ready[%@char[%d]:] EQ 1 then

       iff %@removable[%@char[%d]:] NE 1 .AND. %@remote[%@char[%d]:] NE 1 then

           dir /s /a: %@char[%d]:\

       endiff

   endiff

enddo
```

The people who have mistaken DOS for Windows in other answers will be pleased to know that this 4DOS script — taken from a twenty year old `SYSINF.BAT` script for 4DOS which I updated to newer versions of 4DOS and then ported to 4OS2 — still works, just the same as on 4DOS, with JP Software's TCC/LE on Windows NT 6.1.

Comment: just to say that the OP didn't explicitly exclude Windows to begin with, that was added as a later edit after some Windows answers were posted so there was no "mistaken DOS for Windows"

Comment: On the contrary:  The questioner said DOS, twice, in the very first revision of the question.

Comment: Thanks JdeBP and yes, i did not even talk about win, for me, after win 95, DOS in Windows is just "command line", like linux. DOS is DOS and always be :D

Answer (score 0):

so here is a command line method. Just use %% instead of % in a batch

```
for %d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (ifexist %d: (dir -a -h %d:\*.* /s > %d.txt))
```

Comment: but this also finds on some removable devices, not? For eg. a ZIP/CD/DVD/USB with that letters.

Comment: there is any way to list only hdd, like linux?

Comment: Well there are ways, but I've never tried in a batch. If I have time later I will try to work out a batch method.

Comment: Hmmm...so I see that you have no windows access at all...I guess my question would be, why do you need to ignore for instance the floppy and CD drives?

Comment: I supose it will crash and/or late hours and hours if it does. Doing this batch is a very particulary petition for techs and i dont want any "but..." after :D

Comment: It actually won't do either of those things. Running it would have shown you that.

Comment: It checks if the drive exists. if there is no disk in a removable drive, it will fail with "not ready," and move on. I can envision this failing (stalling, retry prompt) with a read error, but this would not be unique to removable media.

Comment: Breezes right on by the removeable media on my machine.

Answer (score -1):

My answer requires administrator rights.  But in a BAT file run this:

```
echo list volume | diskpart
```

or if you want only the hard drives run this:

```
echo list volume | diskpart | Find /I "Partition"
```

In my script I needed a list of removable media so I could update all of my thumb drives at once.  The nice thing about this is each drive is updated at the same time concurrently.

```
@echo off  
setlocal  

ECHO Searching for removable media. . .  

for /f "usebackq tokens=3 delims= " %%a in (`ECHO List Volume ^| DISKPART ^| FIND /I "Removable"`) do call :Launch %%a  

GOTO:EOF  

:Launch  
  set USB=%1:  
  ECHO Checking drive %USB%   
  IF NOT EXIST %USB%\MDT.bat ECHO Drive %USB% NOT MDT drive && GOTO:EOF  
  ECHO Found thumb drive starting Synch...  
  start %~dp1\Local_MDT_to_USB.bat %USB%  
GOTO:EOF
```

Comment: I asked specifically for "MSDOS", not Windows Command Line